# How to reuse saved classifier created from explorer(in weka) in eclipse java

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka

I have created a classifier in WEKA, i saved it on my hard-disk, now I want to use that classifier in eclipse using weka api.

How can i do this? please guide me to this... thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example of loading a model to predict the value of instances.  The example model is a J48 decision tree created and saved in the Weka Explorer.  It was built from the nominal weather data provided with Weka.  It is called "tree.model".

```
 //load model
String rootPath="/some/where/"; 
Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath+"tree.model");

//predict instance class values
Instances originalTrain= //load or create Instances to predict

//which instance to predict class value
int s1=0;  

//perform your prediction
double value=cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1));

//get the name of the class value
String prediction=originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int)value); 

System.out.println("The predicted value of instance "+
                    Integer.toString(s1)+
                    ": "+prediction);
```

The output from this is:

```
The predicted value of instance 0: no
```

A great beginers resource for the Weka api and Serialization is [here!](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization)